# How to add lowercase field to NSURLRequest header field?

Tags: iphone, nsurlrequest, lowercase, case-sensitive

I'm getting pretty frustrated figuring out how to add a lowercase header field to an NSMutableURLRequest.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MyURLString]];
[urlRequest setValue:@"aValue" forHTTPHeaderField:@"field"];
```

In the example above, "field" gets switched to "Field," since the header field names are case insensitive.  I would think this shouldn't happen, but it does.  The API I am working with is case sensitive, so my GET request is ignored.  Is there any way to override the case switch?

Answer (score 2):

HTTP header fields are [supposed to be case insensitive](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html), so you need to fix your API.

Comment: Or get the 3rd party to fix theirs!

Comment: Well, I'll email their support and see how far I get!  I was hoping there would be a way for me to change the case of my request, but I can't find anything to dodge the case switch.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, they should be, but it's not NSMutableURLRequest's to enforce it. I mean why not get really funky and intercaps the fields?

Answer (score 2):

I have written a blog post on the topic: [Fixing -[NSMutableURLRequest setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:]](http://0xced.blogspot.com/2010/06/fixing-nsmutableurlrequest.html) I suggest you to read it. You will learn how to fix this problem and why you should not fix it.

Comment: That's a great article on the topic, but would you mind fleshing out your answer here with a summary of what you state there? We like to have as much information here as possible, in case the links to articles like this go down. We're starting to see more of that as the site ages.

Answer (score 0):

can u please try with addValue(_:forHTTPHeaderField:)?

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:MyURLString]];
[urlRequest addValue:@"aValue" forHTTPHeaderField:@"field"];
```