# Automatic capitalization of http headers in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift3, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest

How to pass "location" (all letters small-case) in HTTP headers of NSURLRequest or URLSession? I am coding like

```
let session = URLSession.shared
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.addValue("XYZLocation", forHTTPHeaderField: "location")
request.addValue("XYZLoc", forHTTPHeaderField: "loc")
print("Header : \(String(describing: request.allHTTPHeaderFields))")
```

It's always printing `Location: XYZLocation, loc: XYZLoc`. Whereas I want `location:XYZLocation, loc: XYZLoc`. Why 'l' is always getting capitalized in location?

Comment: The reason why (presumably) is that the initial upper-case letter is correct. Why do you wish to lower-case it?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You can't.  The HTTP specification defines Location as the proper form for that header, and iOS automatically canonicalizes the case of all headers.  Further, the HTTP specification requires that all HTTP headers be treated in a case-insensitive fashion, so anything that requires a "location" header is intrinsically broken.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add lowercase field to NSURLRequest header field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543396/how-to-add-lowercase-field-to-nsurlrequest-header-field)

Comment: Also, this is a duplicate.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543396/how-to-add-lowercase-field-to-nsurlrequest-header-field

Comment: Thanks @dgatwood for the useful link, but firstly both links are referencing to the same question :) Secondly, it provides a fix which can not be published on Appstore. Third, if I make my server APIs  headers case-insensitive, then also I have a doubt that if headers get auto-canonicalized as per Apple docs. Then, why iOS is not canonicalizing it?
    `request.addValue("XYZLocation", forHTTPHeaderField: "loc")
    print("Header : \(String(describing: request.allHTTPHeaderFields))")`
Its printing all letters small loc:XYZLocation for me.  Can you please give it a try?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I didn't know that it had posted the "Possible duplicate of" when I flagged it as a dupe.  The purpose of the dupe was not to provide a fix, but rather to point to another answer that explains that there is no good way to fix this in your app, and you shouldn't even try.  The bug is on the server side.  Your server code should not care what case the device sends.

Comment: And the reason it isn't capitalizing "loc" is that "loc" is not one of the standard HTTP headers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).